# Regexp to get content until next div only (not containing div)

Tags: php, regex

I have the following input

```
<div style="s1">title1</div>
<div style="s1">content1</div>
<div style="s1">title2</div>
<div style="s1">content2</div>
```

I know `title1` and `title2` and I want to collect content1 and content2

I would need something like this:

```
<div style="s1">title1</div>.*?<div style="s1">(.*?)</div>
```

but since regexp is greedy, it matches until the end so it returns

```
content1</div>
    <div style="s1">title2</div>
    <div style="s1">content2
```

I would like to add to the pattern a list of tags that should not be included in the match.

Something like:

```
<div style="s1">title1</div>.*?<div style="s1">(.*?[^<div])</div>
```

where I refer with `[^<div]` to a not contain stuff. This should be multiple options, probably with the use of |

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Obligitory link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Now that that is out of the way, just do some dom manipulation and xpath:

```
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);
    $x = new DOMXPath($dom);        

    foreach($x->query("//div") as $node)
    {
       if (trim($node->textContent) == 'title1')
       {
           $content['title1'] = $node->nextSibling->textContent;
       }
    }
```

Now wasn't that easy? So no more regexing html kay?

Comment: +1 true story... I know regex gives people magical warm fuzzy feelings but it is terrible for parsing DOM.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="s1">title1</div>.*<div style="s1">(([^<]|<[^\/])*)</div>
```

Try this - it means find anything excepting < or < not followed by / - if you want, i can add there condition for sub-divs etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the U option = ungreedy :
http://.php.net/manual/fr/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php